# Oracle Store Procedure with BLOB parameter

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, blob

Hi i'm new working with this technologies (Oracle SP ), so I have some problems with it,

To be specific I want to insert a BLOB object over a Store Procedure, currently I work with spring, jboss, java and oracle, my SP is simple than :

```
PROCEDURE SAVE_DATA(data IN BLOB, date IN DATE) IS
next_id number;
BEGIN
  select s_id.nextval into next_id from dual;

  INSERT INTO DATA_TABLE( id, data , date)
  values
  (next_id, data , date);
  COMMIT;

  EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,''||SQLCODE ||'-'||SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,500));
  END SAVE_FAILED_EMAIL;
```

So in the java side, I do something like this:

```
  WrappedConnection wrappedCon = (WrappedConnection) this.getDataSource().getConnection();
        con = (OracleConnection) wrappedCon.getUnderlyingConnection();
        byte[] bytes= IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
        blobObj=con.createBlob(bytes);

  execute(new CallableStatementCreator() {

        public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con)
                throws SQLException {
             String procedure = "call SAVE_DATA(?,?)";

                CallableStatement stm=con.prepareCall(procedure);

                stm.setBlob(1, blobObj);
                stm.setDate(2, date);
            return stm;
        }
    }, new CallableStatementCallback<Map<Integer,Object>>() {

        public Map<Integer, Object> doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) 
        throws SQLException,DataAccessException {
            cs.execute();
            return null;
        }} 
    );
    con.commit();
    con.close();
```

But when I run this part of the code I get the next exception that comes form DB side 
"ORA-22927 invalid LOB locator specified"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a little bit tricky. The first problem you got here is that Oracle needs a propietary BLOB and CLOB instances; here is the javadoc from Spring [OracleLobHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/OracleLobHandler.html):

> While most databases are able to work with DefaultLobHandler, Oracle
>   9i (or more specifically, the Oracle 9i JDBC driver) just accepts
>   Blob/Clob instances created via its own proprietary BLOB/CLOB API, and
>   additionally doesn't accept large streams for PreparedStatement's
>   corresponding setter methods.

But as you are working in JBoss you will also need a [NativeJdbcExtractor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/nativejdbc/NativeJdbcExtractor.html) so Spring can unwrap the underlying connection from [JBoss thread pool wrapper](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.3SP1/connector/org/jboss/resource/adapter/jdbc/WrapperDataSource.html) and then insert the lob in Spring JdbcTemplate.

So, here is the code you need to change:

```
// ...
final byte[] bytes= IOUtils.toByteArray(input);

final OracleLobHandler lobHandler = new OracleLobHandler();
final lobHandler.setNativeJdbcExtractor(new JBossNativeJdbcExtractor());
// ...
new CallableStatementCreator() {

    public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con)
            throws SQLException {
         String procedure = "call SAVE_DATA(?,?)";

            CallableStatement stm=con.prepareCall(procedure);

            lobHandler.getLobCreator().setLobAsBytes(smt, 1, bytes, bytes.length);
            stm.setDate(2, date);
        return stm;
    }
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking Spring jdbc template solution to insert BLOB using stored procedure/query, the following syntax worked for me:

Insert via Queries

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
ps.setBlob(1, inputStream);
```

Insert via Stored Procedure Call

```
Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<>();
inParams.put("pi_some_id", id);
inParams.put("pi_file_blob",  new SqlLobValue(file.getBytes()));        
SqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParams);        
SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = {
                new SqlParameter("pi_some_id", Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter("pi_file_blob", Types.BLOB),
                new SqlOutParameter("po_error_flag", Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("po_message", Types.VARCHAR)};
        
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess().
withProcedureName(storedProcName).withCatalogName(packageName).
declareParameters(sqlParameters);
    Map<String, Object> storedProcResult = simpleJdbcCall.execute(sqlParameterSource);
```